# SQL: Select all rows of the accounts which have certain value in a particular column

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

I have some data in the table1 in this form:

```
ID1     ID2     Col3   Col4 ...
x1      a1       a  
x1      a1       b  
x1      a2       c  
x2      a1       a
x2      a2       b
x2      a2       c
x3      a3       a
x3      a3       d   
x4      a3       d
```

I want to display all rows of the accounts(ID1+ID2) which have 'a' in the Col3 field.
So output should look like

```
ID1     ID2     Col3   Col4 ...
x1      a1       a  
x1      a1       b    
x2      a1       a
x3      a3       a
x3      a3       d
```

This is the query that I am using:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 table1
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT t2.ID1, t2.ID2
   FROM t2 table1
   where t1.ID1 = t2.ID1
   AND t1.ID2 = t2.ID2
   AND t2.Col3 = 'a'
)
```

This query is taking a lot of time. Is there a faster way?

Thanks!!

---

I found one solution:
The table on which I am working has millions of rows. Therefore the query was taking a lot of time. I was able to increase the speed by performing indexing of primary keys on both table.

Thanks!! :)

Comment: why is your desired output having 'b' & 'd' if you only want 'a'?

Comment: I want to display all the rows for combination of id1 and id2 which has one row where Col3 = a
In table1, (x1, a1) combination has one row where Col3 = a, therefore all the rows of combination(x1, a1) is displayed

Comment: See JOIN. Have fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1

**Select from column 1 and matching row from column 2 but Only if table 1 contains the right data in col3**
`SELECT ID1, ID2, Col3 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2  ON Table1.col3 = "a";`

### Solution 2

**Select from column 1 and matching row from column 2 but Only if table 1 and table 2 contains the right data in col3**
`SELECT ID1, ID2, Col3 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2  ON Table1.col3 = "a"  AND Table2.col3 = a;`

Comment: PS due to the vague nature of your question I had to make a few guesses as to what you actually want to know so please don't down vote me if I failed to answer properly, Also I suggest researching "SQL Joins" because the answer is sure to have something to do with an SQL join

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain better what you want? Cause your example result don't look like you say (only 'a' in col3) and your query is redundant i think that query and this will result same:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 table1
```

You will take all result with

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col3 = 'a'
```

Comment: I missed a line in the query that I have written. This should clear stuff.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) referencing this one if it will help provide context.

Comment: It seem being still the same that SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col3 = 'a', cause t1 and t2 are the same table so will match all records

Answer (score 0):

Try this first:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM table1 AS a
JOIN table1 AS b
WHERE a.id1 = b.id1
AND   a.id2 = b.id2 
AND   (a.col3 = 'a' or b.col3 = 'a')
```

If not want you wanted, try the following raw:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS a
JOIN table1 AS b
WHERE a.id1 = b.id1
AND   a.id2 = b.id2 
AND   (a.col3 = 'a' or b.col3 = 'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be the solution

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM t1
WHERE ID1 IN (SELECT ID1 FROM t1 WHERE Col3 LIKE 'a')
```